# Partial update dynamic view on CustomControl | XPages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, partial-views

I have an application with one XPage. It has these custom controls(cc):

```
ccHeader
ccMenu
ccContent
ccFooter
```

Custom control `ccContent` has a combobox, with list of Views in `sessionScope` and dynamic view panel from extension library for XPages. This combobox has an event `OnChange` defined to partial update dynamic view.

What do I need?: Combobox with view list will be deleted and after that I need to assign this partial update function to five links, which are located on `ccMenu` custom control. So, i click on link in `ccMenu`, it returns some view name, assigns it to dynamic view and makes partial update.

How to get id of this dynamic view in `ccMenu` to call partial update?

Comment: Please, post code sample. And I don't get it: can you rephrase your last sentence, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you mean is that you want to have a clean way to let the buttons know which area to partial-refresh when changed:

You could add a property to the ccMenu control along the lines of "viewRefreshId" and pass in the ID of the area to refresh, so you'd end up with a button like this:

```
<xp:button id="viewChanger1" value="View 1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="${compositeData.viewRefreshId}">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript: viewScope.selectedView = 'View 1' }]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Now, there's a question of whether you should try to pass in an ID from something contained within another CC from the main XPage, and I try to avoid that - it would PROBABLY work, but it's a bit messy. I tend to architect similar things so that the part to be refreshed is directly on the XPage (which is to say, I don't use "content" custom controls), so I end up with something like this:

```
<xc:viewSelector viewRefreshId="dynamicViewContainer"/>

<xp:div id="dynamicViewContainer">
    <xe:dynamicView>
        <xe:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="#{viewScope.selectedView}"/>
        </xe:this.data>
    </xe:dynamicView>
</xp:div>
```

The extra container div comes from experience that I had a while ago where refreshing the dynamic view directly caused rendering problems, but I don't know if that's still the case (or if I had run into some other problem).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Everything works like you described. I just moved content to main xpage. About additional div - i tried without it - and everything was just fine. Any troubles with rendering.